# Team Foundation Server :RecursionLimit exceeded

Tags: tfs

Hi we are working in Team Foundation Server 2015, today I was trying to open a backlog item (yesterday I did it without any problem)  but I got this error message "RecursionLimit exceeded ", then I noticed all backlog items have the same problem, what should I do to avoid it? Is there any limit configuration?  [Backlog item message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cpCX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use below ways to narrow down the issue:

- Use another user account to see if the issue related to permission
- Clear IE cache and try it again
- Use another browser such as chrome instead of IE
- [Clear TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/)
- Try to use your account in another machine

Comment: Well we tried , at the end we resolved by removing some pools we have added recently. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the end we resolved by removing some pools  we have added recently.